# Goat Simulator quests are in the wrong map?

Tags: goat-simulator

I've been trying to get all the quests done in Goat Simulator. I've got them all done in Goat City Bay, but for some reason there are some extra quests in GoatVille. For example, the long board, Goat Rider, and the Hyped Up quests are there, but it's impossible to complete them. I've looked all over the map and can't find anything to complete the quests. I'm almost positive that they're not supposed to be there.  How do I complete these quest in GoatVille?

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  In fact it almost certainly would be a bug.  Have you tried taking the tunnel from Goatville to Goat City Bay?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in my game - I have challenges for the stuff that isn't on this map as well.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug. You should contact Coffee Stain and tell them this so the issue is immediately fixed. On what platform are you playing on? If on Android, you can contact the developers through the Playstore, but I am unsure on iOS.